# Add empty space in 'p' tag using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, spacing

I have this code:

```
<div>
  <p id="header-bg-title">Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3</p>
 </div>
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Image 1]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image: Image 2]

As you can see, before *"Line 2"* there is a little bit of space. How can I add this space?

Comment: put each of the text in a span and add class to the span

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing that you can put your "line 2" word in span(inline tag) and give margin left
Example:

```css
.space{

    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p id="header-bg-title">Line 1<br> <span class="space">Line 2</span> <br>Line 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div>
  <p id="header-bg-title">Line 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Line 2<br>Line 3</p>
</div>
```

Use `&nbsp;` as space.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS only solution without changing the HTML code:

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-indent: -10px; /* same as the width below */
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

p::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 10px; /* */
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="header-bg-title">Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.line2{

    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p id="header-bg-title">
        <span class="line1">Line 1<br></span>
        <span class="line2">Line 2<br></span>
        <span class="line3">Line 3</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
<p>
Line 1 <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line 2 <br>
Line 3 <br>
</p>
```

Answer (score -4):

```html
<div style="background-color: blue; width: auto; height: auto; text-align: center; line-height: 100px;font-size: 30px;overflow:hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
  <span>
    Line 1 
  </span>
  <span>
    Line 2
  </span>
  <span>
    Line 3
  </span>
</div>
```